# python stdin and expect

Tags: python, expect

Iam trying to make an expect program talk to python script, I have the following code:

```
spawn "python3" "python.py" 
expect -re "(.*)\r\n"
set command_output $expect_out(1,string)
puts "the result is ($command_output)"
expect -re "(.*)"
send "sss\n"
send "aaa\n"
expect -re "(.*)\r\n"
set command_output $expect_out(1,string)      # my problem. is in the matched string here
puts "the second result is ($command_output)"
```

in the matched string the data I sent (sss and aaa) is also matched, I don't want that

python code :

```
import sys


print(' "hello" mmm uart')


data = sys.stdin.readline()
data2 = sys.stdin.readline()

if data == "sss\n":
    print(str(len(data)))
else:
    print("not sss")
```

I tried using `sys.stdin.flush()` or `sys.stdout.flush()` it did not solve my problem, I tried to put an extra `expect *` to clear the `expect_out(1,string)` it did not solve as well.

can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you truly need expect for. In expect/tcl you could write

```
set command_output [exec python3 python.py << "sss\naaa\n"]
set output_lines [split $command_output \n]
puts "the first result is ([lindex $output_lines 0])"
puts "the second result is ([lindex $output_lines 1])"
```

If you really really want to use expect, the problem is that there's not much you can use as `expect` patterns. You could do:

```
spawn python3 python.py
send "sss\r"
send "aaa\r"
expect eof
set output_lines [split $expect_out(buffer) \n]
puts "the first result is ([string trim [lindex $output_lines 0]])"
puts "the second result is ([string trim [lindex $output_lines 3]])"
```

The list index in the last command is 3 because the two lines sent show up in the buffer.

Comment: thanks for giving me an answer, the thing is that the code in my question was just a demo of something more complex, not using expect is not an option for me. regarding your expect solution, I was hoping for more dynamic solution, in my real application the communication will be more dynamic, the data I will send to python is unknown in advanced, now I know I always can filter it out (like you did by taking the third element),  but I am searching for away where I don't need to concern the data I am sending

Comment: The typical pattern of an expect script is "expect something, save captured parts of the expected text, then send something" -- in the sample python script in the question, there's nothing to expect: if you printed a prompt before each readline, it would be easier to write a more idiomatic expect script.